# How to style a custom app bar using a theme?

Tags: flutter

There is a custom appbar on a page

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 4,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        appBar: MyAppbar(
          tabController: tabController,
        ),
        body: ...
```

where MyAppbar is

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const double tabHeight = 60.0;
    return SizedBox(
      height: widget.preferredSize.height,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TabBar(
            controller: widget.tabController,
            tabs: const [
              SizedBox(
                height: tabHeight,
                child: Tab(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.credit_card,
                    size: Styles.tabIconSize,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(...
```

it looks like

[image]

where that greenish colour comes from a dark theme

```
final darkTheme = ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
  colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
    seedColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 120, 214, 192),
  ),
  primaryColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 120, 214, 192),
  iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.red), // doesn't work?
  primaryIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.red), // doesn't work?
  ...
```

I'd like to make that greenish colour a bit more prominent because now it looks too dull. Is it possible to make it via a theme? It seems that `iconTheme` and `primaryIconTheme` doesn't work at all now.

That colour (a clear(!) colour) looks like below but on the appbar it kind of blends into the background.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab icons in `TabBar` are taking colors from the [`TabBarTheme`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBarTheme-class.html). You can set it in your `ThemeData` like this:

```dart
ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
  tabBarTheme: TabBarTheme(
    labelColor: Colors.red,
    indicatorColor: Colors.orange,
  ),
)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Looks good. Is it possible to set the color for the inactive icon?

Comment: Yes, you can use the `unselectedLabelColor` parameter